# Eclipse error when attempting to build a Phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova, dalvik

I'm getting this error any time I try to launch my Phonegap application in Eclipse:
`Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/phonegap/api/IPlugin;`

This started happening immediately after updating to R14 of the Android tools.  The problem persists after updating to R15.

A friend of mine is able to successfully build the same code on a machine running an earlier version of the SDK tools.

After searching around and seeing various solutions to similar error messages, I've tried completely removing the Android SDK and Eclipse and reinstalling to no effect.

Short of trying to find an earlier version of the SDK tools somewhere, does anybody have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm assuming you don't have two versions of the phonegap.jar in your build path so I would suggest:

- turning off build automatically
- do a clean
- make sure the bin directory in your project is completely clean
- turn on build automatically

Hope that helps.

Comment: No luck. The bin folder is completely empty before the build save for an empty classes folder.  As soon as the build is complete, I hit launch, and it give me the error message in the console.

Comment: I only had 1 version on the path and 2 versions in the bin this also caused this problem for me. After cleaning the bin it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, **Project -> Clean ...**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `libs/` is not a `Source folder` but just the plain `Folder`.

> //I know it's a old topic, but just wanted to help someone Googling
>   for this